# Use IP address or FQDN

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, fqdn, server-setup

I am preparing servers infrastructure consisting MYSQL , LDAP , PHP and FTP.

I have all servers have static public and private IP(LAN). 
Now while configuring SSL i am facing problem of FQDN.

For connecting all servers , should I use direct IP address or FQDN ?
FQDN for internal purposes are secure ? How can I use it ?

For example, ldap.mysite.com , mysql.mysite.com or ftp.mysite.com.
On the other side, i can directly use 100.xxx.yyy.zzz ip address of ldap.mysite.com (for PHP connectivity)

(I absolutely don't want anyone to know subdomains or any internal structure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your DNS infrastructure. Is it steady, reliable and secure enough to meet your criteria?
If it is, you should use FQDN everywhere. It will be of a great help anytime you need to migrate a part of the infrastructure.

Comment: If the DNS infrastructure isn't solid enough then I think the answer is still "use FQDN". And fix the DNS infrastructure.

Comment: Yeah. It is not that hard to get a very reliable and free public DNS service. Broken infrastructure should reallxy be fixed, not just patched up in a blocking way.

Comment: Yepp..i was thinking on that direction only. Passing local IP in public DNS is common practise or not ? I don't want to transfer data over internet..all servers are linked internally.

Comment: Should we create private DNS architecture or get Cloudflare or other other public DNS with SLA ?

Answer (score 2):

FQDN more flexible solution. As you may change ip address just in one place - DNS, without needs to change anything on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you need SSL connectivity for several subdomains, you can install a wildcard SSL certificate for *.mysite.com.

Comment: Yehh my exact findings..i am planning to get wildcard ssl and pass it to all servers..our current architecture all based on self signed certificates..FQDN is one more step toward CA.